# AMP Maximum allowed CSS byte count exceeded for inline style

Tags: php, css, wordpress, amp-html

I have AMP installed on a wordpress site. I have `Failed to prepare AMP pages` error whenever I set to `Transitional` or `Standard`. I check by turning on WP_DEBUG and it shows the following errors. What does the below errors mean?

It seems like some CSS issue but does the fix require a change of css or is something that can be ignored?

**Maximum allowed CSS byte count exceeded for inline style 'font-size: smaller':  (0) [AmpProject\Exception\MaxCssByteCountExceeded]
/bitnami/wordpress/wp-content/plugins/amp/vendor/ampproject/amp-toolbox/src/Exception/MaxCssByteCountExceeded.php:28**

> #0 /bitnami/wordpress/wp-content/plugins/amp/vendor/ampproject/amp-toolbox/src/Dom/Element.php(82): AmpProject\Exception\MaxCssByteCountExceeded::forInlineStyle()
> #1 /bitnami/wordpress/wp-content/plugins/amp/includes/validation/class-amp-validation-manager.php(1686):AmpProject\Dom\Element->setAttribute()
> #2 /bitnami/wordpress/wp-content/plugins/amp/includes/validation/class-amp-validation-manager.php(1534):AMP_Validation_Manager::update_admin_bar_item()
> #3 /bitnami/wordpress/wp-content/plugins/amp/includes/class-amp-theme-support.php(2082):
> AMP_Validation_Manager::finalize_validation()
> #4 /bitnami/wordpress/wp-content/plugins/amp/includes/class-amp-theme-support.php(1678):
> AMP_Theme_Support::prepare_response()
> #5 [internal function]: AMP_Theme_Support::finish_output_buffering()
> #6 /opt/bitnami/wordpress/wp-includes/functions.php(5107): ob_end_flush()
> #7 /opt/bitnami/wordpress/wp-includes/class-wp-hook.php(303): wp_ob_end_flush_all()
> #8 /opt/bitnami/wordpress/wp-includes/class-wp-hook.php(327): WP_Hook->apply_filters()
> #9 /opt/bitnami/wordpress/wp-includes/plugin.php(470): WP_Hook->do_action()
> #10 /opt/bitnami/wordpress/wp-includes/load.php(1097): do_action()
> #11 [internal function]: shutdown_action_hook()
> #12 {main}

Comment: AMP has a limitation of 75KB, in case your theme or any plugin exceeds CSS limit it will throw this error

Comment: Check this https://github.com/ampproject/amp-toolbox-php/issues/19